# How to automatically make the width of a multiline text element so the text inside fits a certain height without overflow?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

Assuming I have a div with some text content inside. Now I want this text element to have a fixed height of, let's say, `200px`. How do I make the width of this element, so that its contents always automatically fit the height perfectly without overflow.

Quick sketch of what I'm aiming for:

[image: quick sketch of what I'm aiming for]

I already tried a lot of methods like using `min-content`, `display: grid`, or `display: flexbox`, but didn't find any working solution. It would be super helpful if any of you who have a clue, could give me a hint. Thanks.

Comment: try adding property ```overflow-x : auto;```

Comment: @Frost thanks. do you mean in conjunction with width: min-content? that doesn't seem to work..

Comment: no simply the overflow property, not in conjunction with min-content.

Comment: @Frost ok. but then it just fills the full-width of the container element without considering the height.

Comment: Well, if you would not mind scroll bars then, simply set ```overflow : auto;```. This one takes care of overflowing in both horizontal and vertical directions.

Comment: How about the width? You want the width to be specific like `200px` or to be the window's width?

Comment: @GibinEalias thanks:) I want the text container width to be specific. not that of the window

Comment: Great. Hope this is what you are looking for - https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/RMapJe Try removing the line `overflow: hidden;` and see the difference by yourself.

Comment: @GibinEalias Thanks for putting the effort in! But actually I'm looking for a way to automatically set that width. You just set that width to 200px manually.

Comment: What do you mean by 'automatically set the height'. How are you planning to achieve it?

Comment: @GibinEalias sorry, I obviously meant to automatically set the width based on the content

Comment: Hope you are aware that the width of an element is, by default, set either by its contents(inline element) or the width of its container (block element). Unless and until you specify a width value, it won't be changed. For example, use a <div> or a <p> tag and fill it with lot of texts. Now shrink your window and you can see the text wrapping to new lines increasing its height. Now if you want to set the height restricted to a maximum on `200px` you can do that in css like in my codepen. Hope this makes it clear for you.